# How to parse data to coresponding columns in awk

Tags: python, shell, parsing, awk

I have TAB separate data and I would like to parse data like this:

Input :

```
more input.tsv

A  B  5  A1,A2,A3,A4,A5   B1,B2,B3,B4,B5
C  D  3  C1,C2,C3  D1,D2,D3
```

And required output is:

```
A  B  5  A1  B1
A  B  5  A2  B2
.
.
A  B  5  A5  B5
C  D  3  C1  D1
.
C  D  3  C3  D3
```

So it is mean keep first three columns and split 4th and 5th to corresponding values. Number of values in 4th and 5th columns is define value in 3th column.

I would prefer awk or maybe python with example explanation - to easy understand and learn something.

My try without any loop:

```
awk '{OFS="\t"}{split($4,arr4,",") split($5,arr5,","); print $1,$2,$3,arr4[1],arr5[1]; print $1,$2,$3,arr4[2],arr5[2]}'
```

Comment: You are not actually asking a question. Not even implicitly, by describing the problems your current approach has. Please read [ask]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you can do something like this:

```
tempstr = """A\tB\t5\tA1,A2,A3,A4,A5\tB1,B2,B3,B4,B5
C\tD\t3\tC1,C2,C3\tD1,D2,D3"""

data = []

for line in tempstr.split("\n"):
    line = line.split("\t")
    split_column_1 = line[3].split(",")
    split_column_2 = line[4].split(",")
    if len(split_column_1) != len(split_column_2):
        print("Something wrong")
    else:
        for c1,c2 in zip(split_column_1,split_column_2):
            data.append((line[0],line[1],line[2],c1,c2))

for d in data:
    print("\t".join(d))
```

## Output:

```
A   B   5   A1  B1
A   B   5   A2  B2
A   B   5   A3  B3
A   B   5   A4  B4
A   B   5   A5  B5
C   D   3   C1  D1
C   D   3   C2  D2
C   D   3   C3  D3
```

## With TSV file

You can use the csv module to process your data:

```
import csv

data = []

with open('resources/data.tsv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
    for row in csv_reader:
        split_column_1 = row[3].split(",")
        split_column_2 = row[4].split(",")
        if len(split_column_1) != len(split_column_2):
            print("Something wrong")
        else:
            for c1, c2 in zip(split_column_1, split_column_2):
                data.append((row[0], row[1], row[2], c1, c2))

for d in data:
    print("\t".join(d))
```

## Explanation

1. Open file with csv module. The advantage is it already do a split on the delimiter we specify. Default should be "," but we are using `\t` as we have a tsv file.

```
with open('resources/data.tsv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
```

2. We go through each row / line. Also a feature of the csv module to do it easy with a for loop.

`for row in csv_reader:`

3. Now we split the fourth and fith column on "," because they are still strings. Now we have a list with the splitted elements.

```
split_column_1 = row[3].split(",")
split_column_2 = row[4].split(",")
```

4. If the length of this two are not the same then something is wrong with the data and can lead to unexpected events. (depends on your code) so to account for that we check if this is the case (if your data doesn't have any error it will never be true)

```
if len(split_column_1) != len(split_column_2):
    print("Something wrong")
```

5. We save all the data as a tuple in a list. You can later also access this data in a later step if you need (e.g. `data[3][3] # 4th row, 4th element -> A4`

```
else:
    for c1, c2 in zip(split_column_1, split_column_2):
        data.append((row[0], row[1], row[2], c1, c2))
```

6. Print it nicely so that it looks like your expected output. Basically you can use join on a string (in our case we take `\t`) and as a parameter use a tuple/list. Now he concat all elements of the tuple/list with the string on the left:

```
for d in data:
    print("\t".join(d))
```

Comment: you could use zip function when iterating (more pythonic than iterating over the range of the length). `for element1, element2 in zip(split_column_1, split_column_2):`

Comment: Thank you! If my file is save as input.tsv, how can I load it to script? Just edited in my question.

Comment: @Boendal thank you so much thats great - work like a charm. Could you please explain second for cycle?

Comment: @Paul see my edit... maybe I should read more carefully I explained everything... anyway if you have further question let me know.

Comment: @Boendal that absolutely amazing explanation! Thank you so much for clear and nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, haven't tested it as of now.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="\t"
}
{
  num1=split($4,array1,",")
  num2=split($5,array2,",")
  till=num1>num2?num1:num2
  for(j=1;j<=till;j++){
    print $1,$2,$3,array1[j],array2[j]
  }
  delete array1
  delete array2
}
'  Input_file
```

Testing of above code without setting field separator as TAB:

```
awk '
{
  num1=split($4,array1,",")
  num2=split($5,array2,",")
  till=num1>num2?num1:num2
  for(j=1;j<=till;j++){
    print $1,$2,$3,array1[j],array2[j]
  }
  delete array1
  delete array2
}
' Input_file

A B 5 A1 B1
A B 5 A2 B2
A B 5 A3 B3
A B 5 A4 B4
A B 5 A5 B5
C D 3 C1 D1
C D 3 C2 D2
C D 3 C3 D3
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Output is empty.

Comment: @Paul, if your Input_file is NOT tab delimited then you could try removing BEGIN section's FS, OFS values and give it a try?

Comment: Input file is TAB delimited. Good news is, that there is no error. Bad news is that output is still empty.

Comment: @Paul, I have tested my code successfully and looks like your file is NOT having TAB delimiters, when I tried removing this code's BEGIN section it worked for me,please see my edit where I added which output I am getting, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Good regex with sed loop:

```
# recreate input
# tr to replace spaces with tabs, as the input is tsv
tr -s ' ' '\t' <<EOF |
A  B  5  A1,A2,A3,A4,A5   B1,B2,B3,B4,B5
C  D  3  C1,C2,C3  D1,D2,D3
EOF
# sed script
sed -E '
   # label a
   : a
   # take the last items after `,` comma
   # and add a new line to the pattern space with the two items
   # and remove the last items from the list in the first line
   s/([^\t]+\t[^\t]+\t[^\t]+\t)(.+),([^\t]+)\t(.+),([^\n]+)/\1\2\t\4\n\1\3\t\5/
   # if the last substitution was successfull, branch to label a
   t a
'
```

[on repl gives the following output](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/DeterminedVillainousWebpage):

```
A   B   5   A1  B1
A   B   5   A2  B2
A   B   5   A3  B3
A   B   5   A4  B4
A   B   5   A5  B5
C   D   3   C1  D1
C   D   3   C2  D2
C   D   3   C3  D3
```

And a oneliner without extended regex:

```
sed ':a;s/\([^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t\)\(.*\),\([^\t]*\)\t\(.*\),\([^\n]*\)/\1\2\t\4\n\1\3\t\5/;ta'
```